# Does Bayesian modeling result in fat-tail distributions?

Tags: bayesian, kurtosis

Let's say we have an univariate dataset x that follow a gaussian with parameters (m, s).
Under a frequentist methodology, m and s are estimated using MLE and x is modeled as N(m_hat, s_hat).

Using the bayesian approach, lets say we put a prior on m. Then the model for x becomes f(x|m) ~ N(m, s). Computing the joint distribution f(x, m) and then the marginal distribution of f(x), wouldn't we get a fatter tail marginal distribution of f(x) than N(m_hat, s_hat) obtained from the frequentist approach?

If x is truly normal, why are we modeling it using a fat-tail distribution? Or am I missing anything?

Comment: The sampling model still is a Normal model, whose parameters are inferred from the data $x$, incl. the ensuing uncertainty, while the marginal density is only used as a normalisation constant or as a model assessment.

Comment: You seem to refer to the *predictive distribution* which is indeed often fat-tailed.

Comment: Is it valid to claim that maximum likelihood estimation produces an estimate for the marginal distribution $f(x)$? It seems wrong to me.